# create a JSON object that allows different name

Tags: c++, json

I am creating a JSON file able to read measured value. I have the following structure:

```
{ "object":
  {"object name 1":
   {"type":
    {"type name":
     {"properties":[
         {"measure1": 10,
          "measure2":5
          }
      }
     }
    },
 
  {"object name 2":
   {"type":
    {"type name":
     {"properties":[
         {"measure1": 10,
          "measure2":5
          }
      }
     }
    }
   }
}
```

now object 1 and  2 are exactly the same but they have different name. Is there a possibility of merging these two objects and provide a list of names?

I tried the following without success:

```
 { "object":
  {["object name 1","object name 1"]:
   {"type":
```

I am using C++ to read the file as follows:

```
std::string s =this->filename;
std::ifstream json_file_stream(s);
  
  if(!json_file_stream)
      error("Could not open Json file!");

nlohmann::json radionuclide_json;
json_file_stream >> radionuclide_json;
```

the code crashes at the last line

Comment: Array can not be used as field name. You should make a dedicated field instead: `"name": [ "object name 1", "object name 2" ]`

Comment: I use nlohmann::json all the time, and I always read the file contents and then use json::parse(string) to parse its contents. You can wrap this in a try-catch block to see what he's complaining about, though. nlohmann will throw exceptions on parse errors.

Comment: @user7860670 how do you mean? something like the following?   { "object":
  {"name": ["object name 1","object name 2"]:
   {"type":
    {"type name":
     {"properties":[
         {"measure1": 10,
          "measure2":5
          }
      }
     }
    },